# Flutter : Handle push notification message that come from non-firebase source

Tags: flutter

My app is setup to use firebase for push notification. I see the push and the data when I send a message thru firebase

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
        print('Got a message whilst in the background!');
        print('Message data: ${message.data}');
      });

      //trap when app is in foreground
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
        (RemoteMessage message) {
}
```

Now , another third party vendor(iterable) is sending push message. I see the popup but how do I get the data from the message. The firebase handler does not get triggered

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the message data from the FirebaseMessaging if you are not using Firebase.

Firebase messaging is exclusive to firebase, so you can't use it to get other third-party notifications. Your third-party notification provider will provide SDK, you need to integrate it into your app, in order to get the data from the message.

Comment: Ok.. but I see their is a plugin --flutter_local_notifications. Is it not possible to trap the message from Firebase with Firebase handle and  flutter_local_notifications handler will get notification from other vendor

Comment: Flutter local notifications are for local notifications, meaning: the notifications are triggered from your app, not using any external services.

Comment: What is the third-party notification service you are using?

Comment: Thank you.. I am using firebase and that is working. The other third party is Iterable. I get the push from iterable. Clicking it opens my app . However, as you told me the firebase listen handler will not get executed.. I need the payload from the message